# How can I push using a keyboard shortcut in GitKraken?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, git

I am trying to make a keyboard shortcut for GitKraken to push. I have been unable to find a way to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mureinik says in [his answer](https://superuser.com/a/1388495/32245), there is no one keyboard shortcut.

However, if not touching the mouse suffices, this is a workaround:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the [Fuzzy Finder](https://support.gitkraken.com/start-here/fuzzy-finder/)
2. Type *push*

   [image]
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Keyboard Shortcuts docuementation](https://support.gitkraken.com/start-here/keyboard-shortcuts), there's no shortcut for pushing, unfortunately.